# How to return the values of elements of an arrray?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Code keeps throwing

> Subscript out of range

```vb
Sub test()
    
    Dim arr As Variant    
    arr = Range("a1", "a6").Value  
    a = LBound(arr)
    b = UBound(arr)
    
    For i = a To b
        MsgBox arr(i)
    Next
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not `for each e in arr`?

Comment: it is a 2d array: `MsgBox arr(i,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays pulled from ranges in excel are always two-dimensional which is a pain (compared to say google sheets appscripts where it's just arrays within  arrays). A fabulous resource of Excel Arrays is from the late Chip Pearson who posted [this site years ago](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm).

Anyway, as Scott said... you just have to do two nested level...

```
Sub test()
Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
arr = Range("A1", "A6").Value
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        
            MsgBox arr(i, j)
            
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe the various examples I read didn't bother to mention that. I'm still confused that LBOUND(arr) wouldn't give answer in 2D, or that the error mesg was so generic.